# A property for finite subsets of real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers

Let $B$ be a **finite** subset of real numbers. Then, is it true
that there exists $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that

(1) $(A-A)\cap (B-B)=\{ 0\}$,

(2) $(A-A)+B=\mathbb{R}$?

Not that if $B$ is a singleton, then it is true by choosing $A=\mathbb{R}$,
and if $|B|>1$ then $A-A$ can not be a subgroup (if $A-A$ is a subgroup, then $|\mathbb{R}:A-A|=|B|\geq 2$ that is a contradiction). Here, $B-B=\{ b-\beta:b,\beta\in B\}$, $A+B=\{a+b:a\in A,b\in B\}$.

Also see [Two uncountable subsets of real numbers without any interval and two relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3475722/two-uncountable-subsets-of-real-numbers-without-any-interval-and-two-relations) .

Answer (score -1):

Take $A=\{0\}$ regardless of $B$, if $B$ is non-empty. $0 \in B-B$ always and $A-A=\{0\}$ trivially, so $(A-A) \cap (B-B) = \{0\}$.

If $A$ is finite and $B$ too, $A-A$ is finite and so is $(A-A) + B$ and so never equals $\Bbb R$.

$\Bbb R$ has no finite subgroups. I see no point in this question..

Comment: So it fails for your subset A.  Now show it fails for all other subsets of R.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I just note that the first condition is trivial to satisfy and the second one impossible to satisfy within the realm of finite sets.

Comment: The problem per se only required B to be finite.  The title could induce  A to be finite but only OP knows.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma It is clear that $A$ must be an uncountable subset of real numbers (so $A$ cannot be finite!).