# About sub-factors of real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, real-numbers, cardinals

For every subset $A$ of real numbers, we call $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ a sub-factor related to $A$ if:

(1) $(A-A)\cap (B-B)=\{ 0\}$,

(2) $(A-A)+B=\mathbb{R}$.

We can show that every subset $A$ has related sub-factors. Now, my questions are:

(a) Is there a subset $A$ with a related **finite** and an **infinite** sub-factors $B_1$, $B_2$, respectively?

(b) Is it true that for every two cardinal numbers $2\leq\alpha\leq \beta\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$ there exists a subset $A$ with two sub-factors $B_1, B_2$ satisfying $|B_1|=\alpha$
and $|B_2|=\beta$

(it is clear that (a) is satisfied if (b) is true).

Note that
$B-B=\{ b-\beta:b,\beta\in B\}$, $A+B=\{a+b:a\in A,b\in B\}$, and see

[Two uncountable subsets of real numbers without any interval and two relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3475722/two-uncountable-subsets-of-real-numbers-without-any-interval-and-two-relations) ,

https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219498820501017?journalCode=jaa.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Both* conditions $(1)$ and $(2)$ must hold simultaneously, is that so?

Comment: Yes, both conditions must be hold.